# Google Analytics Credential

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am working on Google Analytics and am using the Embed API to have some data be reflected on my site. Is there any way to embed my credentials (google account and password) in my script so that I won't be prompted for my account and password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to embed your username and password credentials into the web page because then they'll be visible to anyone viewing the source of your site. [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) was created to solve this problem, and the answer to your question is to go through the OAuth process server-side.

The Google Analytics Demos & Tools site has a demo with instructions for doing server-side auth with the Embed API:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

Comment: Thank you.
Though, using this server side auth, the report will be visible to the public, with out asking them my credential ? I want my site users to see the report with out being asked my google (gmail) credential, that was my intention.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? Is your site publicly accessible or do you have some sort of login system? If you're site is publicly accessible then it's the same thing, and if you have a login system, then you don't have to worry about it because only authorized users will see your data.

Comment: It's an intranet site.
But, what do you mean when you say " If you're site is publicly accessible then it's the same thing " ?

Comment: You said: "using this server side auth, the report will be visible to the public", but that's not true. It's only visible to the people who can see the webpage you're showing it one. If it's an intranet site than you'll be fine.

Comment: I was trying to copy and paste the JSON file (Key File) to my script file, but it keeps giving me errors. And, the other thing, instead of installing the Google API Client Library for Python, can I include it using a script tag ?

Comment: Since I am using an Office 365, I think that is why it is not allowing me to check in the JSON Key File into my script list. The thing is the list is in an admin page and no one would have the access for that (as they can't have the access for the source code).

Comment: Philip
As I was trying to mention earlier, am working on Office365 and that doesn't allow me to add a .json file. What do you recommend in this case ?